# How to delete row in SqliteDataBase?

Tags: android, sql, delete-row

Hello in my app i want to delete only rows with the same year and month :

for deleting rows by month it works:

```
public void deleteMonth(int month){
    open();
    myDb.delete(TABLE_DAY, "month = ?", new String[] {month+""});
    close();
}
```

but for deleting rows by month and years it crashes here is what i tried:

```
public void deleteMonth(int month ,int year){
    open();
    myDb.delete(TABLE_DAY, "month = ? , year = ?", new String[] {month+"",year+""});
    close();
}
```

I solve it :

```
public void deleteMonth(int month ,int year){
    open();
    myDb.delete(TABLE_DAY, "month = ? and year = ?", new String[] {month+"",year+""});
    close();
}
```

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: I fix it with replacing "month = ? , year = ?" with  "month = ? and year = ?"

Comment: Welcome to S.O!  There should be an option to answer your own question, instead of leaving a comment.

Comment: You can remove the **useless** `+""`, since they serve **no purpose**.